# С++ трюк с использованием необьявленных классов

Tags: visual-c++, c++

В общем писал прогу на DirectX и меня заинтересовала такая вещь. Известно, что все интерфейсы в com это структуры. В DirectX SDK есть фреймворк , который объединеют шейдеры в файлы эффектов. И там есть интерфейс `ID3DX11EffectVariable` от которого наследуются `ID3DX11EffectScalarVariable`, `ID3DX11EffectVectorVariable` и т.д. Самое интересное, что у `ID3DX11EffectVariable` есть методы `ID3DX11EffectScalarVariable* AsScalar() = 0`, `ID3DX11EffectVectorVariable* AsVector() = 0` и т.д. Если взять и закодить такое :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct B
{
public:
    virtual A* getA() = 0;
};

struct A : public B
{
public:
    A* getA() { cout << "i don't understand it" << endl; return NULL; }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    B* b = new A();
    b->get();
    return 0;
}
```

то этот код не скомпилируется, так как A ещё не объявлен. 
Но там перед объявлением интерфейса ID3DX11EffectVariable идут строчки наподобии

```
typedef interface ID3DX11EffectScalarVariable ID3DX11EffectScalarVariable;
typedef interface ID3DX11EffectVectorVariable ID3DX11EffectVectorVariable;
```

и т.д. interface причем тоже самое, что написать struct. 
Прописал у себя таким образом

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct B
{
public:
    virtual struct A* getA() = 0;
};

struct A : public B
{
public:
    A* getA() { cout << "i don't understand it" << endl; return NULL; }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    B* b = new A();
    b->get();
    return 0;
}
```

и все скопилировалось и вывело фразу.Если вместо struct прописать class, то будет тоже работать. Объясните, что за чудеса происходят тут такие ? Это такое есть в С++ стандарте или это чисто фича от MS ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, в Си (и в С++) есть [понятие](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration)  `struct forward declaration`, можно описать имя структуры  и использовать **указатель на нее**  до определения ее полей.

Обычно используют при конструировании списков, деревьев и проч. контейнеров.

Иногда это применяют для описания структуры в разных .h файлах, часто с целью сокрытия полей структуры, используемой в прототипах функций  в пользовательском интерфейсе.